# kdb+ Q : select from table where column value =

Tags: kdb

How do i select all rows from a table where a specific column value equals something?
i have tried the following:

```
select from tablname where columnvalue = value
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do:

```
q)table:([]a:1 2 3 4 5;b:`a`b`c`d`e;c:`hi`bye`bye`bye`hi)
q)table
a b c
-------
1 a hi
2 b bye
3 c bye
4 d bye
5 e hi
q)select from table where c=`bye
a b c
-------
2 b bye
3 c bye
4 d bye
```

Comment: you can also apply the same for numeric columns 
  `select from table where a =1`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
q)tbl:([] a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:7 8 9)
q)tbl
a b c
-----
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
q)select a from tbl
a
-
1
2
3
```

Comment: thanks, how would i select from tbl where a = something?

Comment: Are you checking for column values within a column or checking if a column exist?